# ASP.NET Core 3.1 services.AddSession(); causes crash

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

When I add

```
services.AddSession();
```

to my startup in my core 3.1 I get

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.ISessionStore Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore'.) on stack:   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

At no time did I as for `DistributedSessionStore`, I just added the line `AddSession` and did not add any nuget packages, where is it getting this data from?

When I go to the definition on `services.AddSession()` it takes me to

```
Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
```

Quite surprised as to what this error is all about.

Comment: The session middleware needs the `IDistributedCache` implementation. By default the provided implementation is/should be `InMemoryDistributedCache`, unless you replace it with something different like using Redis for distributed caching, then the cache wont be in-memory (within your application) but redis will be used instead. This allows easily to extend the sessions in a distributed manner. Not sure where or why the exception comes though.

Comment: You could try adding `AddMemoryCache`. Usually memory cache should be added as part of `AddMvC` or `AddControllersWithViews`, but maybe in your conseltation it doesn't. Are you using pure WebAPI w/o any razor pages or views? If so, using session is a design flaw. WebAPI is for restful services, and these are stateless (so no session, everything required should be provided per request). You'll run into serious trouble later on if you try to run a session along of a WebAPI/Restful API

Comment: @Tseng Thank's for the comments, all things being equal the error is quite misleading as I have no clue who is adding the DI or who is asking for it. I guess it's where services are backing sites and same session is to be used.. no idea why else it is using distributed interfaces if not intended to share...

Comment: I told you why. Its using it by default because Session can be handled in distributed manner (i.e. when running multiple instances of your application). By default it [MemoryDistributedCache](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryDistributedCache.cs) which is **NOT** distributed. This one is only added if no other distributed cache is added. If you add Redis as distributed cache, then the `MemoryDistributedCache` wont be used. But it only happens on some of the `AddXxx` calls. For others, you may have to  register it manually

Comment: For cases where it doesn't you have to use `AddMemoryCache()` to your service registrations (I suspect you are using WebAPI, that is using `services.AddControllers()`). And in this cases you **SHOULDN'T USE SESSIONS**. WebAPI/Restful APIs should be stateless. A session is state**ful**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only way to safely test for session is to use some code like this:

```
if(HttpContext.Features.Get<ISessionFeature>()?.Session != null && HttpContext.Session.IsAvailable)
{
...
}
```